# Dynamic scope variable assign Angular

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, scope

I have the name of my form in `$scope.model` variable and its adding dynamically. I wanted to change the value of the form field according to `$scope.model`.
For example

```
 $scope.model = 'form.field.text';
 $scope.[$scope.model]= 'new value';
```

But i it doesn't change the value of `$scope.form.field.text`. How can I do this?
Here's [my plunkr](http://jsfiddle.net/8hkbdq20/)

Comment: I guess it referring wrong model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you need to use $parse service which is used by Angular internally for exactly this purpose:

```
function ctrl($scope, $parse) {
  $scope.form = {
    field: {
      text: ''
    }
  };
  $scope.form.field.text = 'Myvalue';

  $scope.model = 'form.field.text';

  $parse($scope.model).assign($scope, 'new value');
  console.log($scope.form.field.text);
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/8hkbdq20/1/